# как адаптировать слайд swiperjs?

Tags: javascript, css

мне нужно адаптировать слайд swiper js, когда размер экрана будет  width:576px; слайд нужен показываться  по одному а когда больше нужно по 3

Comment: У Swiper отличная документация, жаль её не читают.. [Параметр breakpoints](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-breakpoints), [пример использования](https://codesandbox.io/s/e56nh3?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле конфигурации необходимо прописать параметр breakpoints и задать ему необходимые брекпоинты и значения, например:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  // Default parameters
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  // Responsive breakpoints
  breakpoints: {
    // when window width is >= 320px
    320: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    // when window width is >= 480px
    480: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    // when window width is >= 640px
    640: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 40
    }
  }
})
```